# Flutter: What do you think is the best state management library to use with go_router navigation package?

Tags: flutter, navigation, state-management

I'm trying to design an application for personal use and I'm going to use go_router package for navigation. What state management package do you think goes well with the go_router library?

At first I wanted to use GetX as the state management library (because this state management library is what I'm most comfortable with) but it seems that it doesn't go well with go_router package. (I can use GetX's navigation but I just wanted to try out go_router for this project).

I just want to hear opinions of other flutter developers! Please let me know what you think!

Comment: you can visit my given link, and let me know. please

Answer (score -1):

I think that you can use Getx Route Navigation. I think it is the best of the others flutter framework.
and also you can flow the link
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ykGNGm7zf2Y&list=PLCaS22Sjc8YR32XmudgmVqs49t-eKKr9t&index=6

Comment: Thanks for the link! Yes I know I can use Getx Route Navigation but I just wanted to practice using go_router for this project! I'll look into the videos though, thanks!

Comment: you can accept my ans and up vote plz

Comment: @JakeSeo plz ggg